# Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './requirements.txt' Python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, pip, bitcoin, requirements.txt

I am trying to use this [code](https://github.com/scottjbarr/bitfinex) from github.

The first three commands to get this started are:

```
pip install bitfinex

bitfinex-poll-orderbook

pip install -r ./requirements.txt
```

The first two work perfectly fine and I am able see the orderbook for Bitfinex, a bitcoin trading exchange. When I put the third line I get the following error

```
Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './requirements.txt'
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: run the command from inside the project folder where requirements.txt exists

Comment: Okay, so [do you know what does it do?](https://pip.readthedocs.org/en/1.1/requirements.html) I think `pip install bitfinex` command can auto install the requirements. Also I think you didn't download the project via git or browser, so there's no  `requirements.txt`. If `pip` didn't install that, you could find it in  the project folder on Github [here](https://github.com/scottjbarr/bitfinex/blob/develop/requirements.txt)

Comment: when I run pip install bitfinex it says my requirements are already satisfied and are in the appropriate locations

Comment: how did you fix it, I got the same issue although I run pip install -r requirements.txt from the same folder

Answer (score 1):

You should run that only from a clone of the repository, and only if you want to do development of that library.

Comment: this helped but I still have another error.
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip-build-AUyHaP/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-t_Dx3j-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-AUyHaP/lxml

Comment: The file is requiring `lxml==3.3.1`, but it  isn't available in the PyPI  anymore. You'll need to get it from somewhere else... Or try changing the `requirements.txt` file

Comment: I downloaded that fire and still had an error
Command "/usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/zl/ny6y70vn3lb22pyz9cxl75j80000gn/T/pip-build-oPRVYA/lxml/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/zl/ny6y70vn3lb22pyz9cxl75j80000gn/T/pip-O7ugup-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zl/ny6y70vn3lb22pyz9cxl75j80000gn/T/pip-build-oPRVYA/lxml

Comment: [This](https://github.com/lxml/lxml) is the repository, but you'll need to find the commit yourself

Comment: where do I place that folder?